# stop() animation for set time

Tags: javascript, jquery

In a game I am creating where the user has to click numbers in accordance to the question, I have added a freeze icon which stops the timer for 3 seconds.

I also want this freeze icon to stop all the moving divs for 3 seconds and then resume to the normal animation.

I have tried this..

```
$('#container').children().stop(3000);
```

But it doesn't work. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Better to use `.delay(3000)`

```
$('#container').children().delay(3000);
```

checkout the docs: http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Comment: where did you add this `delay(3000)`?

Comment: Ow sorry I forgot to update it. I placed it in the $(".character").click(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass("freeze")) { part @Jai

Comment: for some reason fiddle will not let me update so I have a code pen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/czwgm @Jai

Comment: Can you see the freeze icon now? @Jai

Comment: Did you find the problem, I have had no luck @jai